# Cannot get QtPrintSupport To Work

Tags: qt, printing, build, wix, qwt

I have tried dozens of different implementations. The tricky issue is that the print dialog will show up and work correctly on my development machine, yet when I build the .msi file and deploy to another machine the print button effectively does nothing. It is supposed to render a graph with information from the appropriate ui and I have ruled out that it was using the qwt library improperly because (even though I can't seem to get it to install correctly on any other machine other than the dev machine) the graphs made using the qwt libraries render properly after the program is installed, just the print button does work.

Here are the important lines to my .pro file that will pertain to any linking or possible printing issues as far as I can tell:

```
QT += core gui sql printsupport network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = static-control-panel
TEMPLATE = app

symbian: LIBS += -lftd2xx
else:unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$quote($$PWD/lib/) -lftd2xx \
    -L$$quote($$PWD/lib/) -lqwt

INCLUDEPATH += $$quote($$PWD/include)
DEPENDPATH += $$quote($$PWD/include)

CONFIG += qwt
```

Inside the .cs file that actual has the print button I have tried `#include <QtPrintSupport>`, `#include "QtPrintSupport"`, `#include "QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog"`, `#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>` and any and every other possible variation.

I am building the project using WiX and candle and light to build it. WiX is a simple markup language that will specify which files to include in the .msi file and the PrintSupport inclusion is identical to any of the other included libraries.

I have also tried AdvancedInstaller and received the same results.

I have tried replacing the .dll files in the install directory after the application has been installed on another machine with newer versions of the .dll files, and with the same old versions from the dev machine in case they just weren't making it into the .msi. Using the old .dlls I get the same unresponsive button. Using the new .dlls will result in the application complaining that it cannot find the correct version of the .dll and it crashes, this is particularly relevant when I replace the qwindows.dll, I guess the .dlls are not backwards compatible?

I see nothing specifying the version of .dll files that will be included in the WiX file when I build it either. Could it be something to do with the versioning of qwt and QtPrintSupport? Any insight into this problem would be extremely appreciated, and if anything is unclear or more code examples or information is needed, please don't hesitate to ask, and thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the version of the files which get included in your .msi package by making use of a tool called Orca.
Orca is part of the windows installer SDK. To install Orca, you will have to download the latest Windows SDK and choose a specific optional component to install(I dont recollect the exact optional component to choose to get Orca, I recall that there is no  need to install the full Windows SDK)

After you install Orca, open your msi package in Orca and Navigate to the "File" table. Search for your specific file and see the version of the files included.

-The other thing i would suggest you to do is to generate a verbose installer log .
Please take a look at

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/03/29/help-me-help-you-if-you-have-setup-bugs.aspx

The log will give you information about  whether the files are being copied and any other information that might help you.

-The third thing, i would suggest you to figure out is if all of the dependencies are in place.

If you are familiar with the tool called "ProcMon" from the SysInternals suite, you can set Filters in this tool for all the dependent dll files. ProcMon can then indicate to you if any of the dependencies were not found.

-The 4th thing you might want to confirm is if there are any special operations required to get this to work. Such as registering the dll, creating any special registry entries etc.

See if you can figure out something and then we can take this forward.

Comment: Wow finally! The ProcMon did it, thank you for suggesting such a great tool. It was able to point out this simple problem that has plagued me for a few months now... as careful as I was being, the install folder for the print functionality was printersupport while the program was looking for printsupport (no 'er') I renamed the folder and it instantly worked on machines that had the previous version installed. Thank you again for the suggestion, and any one having similar issues in the future, the ProcMon or other similar tools are a must use to figure out missing dll issues.

Comment: I am glad that the stack overflow community was of help to you.